# Maintaining proper spacing in Java

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting

I made a program that should output 2 lists of strings (anywhere between 2 and 5) at the end of the line, I want to print an int in brackets.

I am having trouble right justifying the int and the brackets.

All of the printf formatting does not help with moving the int and its surrounding brackets!

```
while (dealerPoints < 17 && playerBust == false) {
    System.out.printf("\nDealer has less than 17. He hits...\n");       
    int nextDealerCard = dealCard();
    dealerPoints += cardValue(nextDealerCard);
    dealerHand += faceCard(nextDealerCard);                             
    System.out.printf("Dealer: %s\t[%d]\n", dealerHand, dealerPoints);              
    System.out.printf("Player: %s\t[%d]\n", playerHand,  playerPoints);
}
```

When there are 4 strings on one line and only 2 on the other, the int and brackets don't align with each other (the one after 4 strings, gets tabbed over too far)

Comment: What does it even mean to "right justify". This is a console we're talking about. \t is also not going to help too much

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("Dealer: %s\t[%10d]\n", "lala", 22222);
System.out.printf("Player: %s\t[%10d]\n", "hoho", 33);
```

Outputs:

```
Dealer: lala    [     22222]
Player: hoho    [        33]
```

is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to right justify, you can either 
 - write the output in a file as a CSV and open it in an excel like program
 - create a utility class that will make any input string a constant length:

```
public static String fixedCharCount( String input, int length ) {
    int spacesToAdd = length - input.lengh();
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(input);
    for( int i=0; i<spacesToAdd; i++) {
        buff.append(" ");
    }
    return buff.toString();
}
```

You can also loop on all your data befor display to see what is the longest String in your table and adapt the length to it (the code is not complete: you must check 'spacesToAdd' is positive.